# display how much time is left until shutdown

Tags: python-3.x, time, os.system

```
import time as t
import os

print("Timed Shutdown")
run = int(input("Please enter a shutdown time in minutes: "))
run *= 60
while run != 0:
    run -= 1
    t.sleep(1)
    print("Your system willl close in:", str(int(run/60)), "minutes")

os.system("shutdown -s")
```

I'm trying to make a program that shuts down the computer after a specific time entered in minutes by the user. I would like to make the print statement from inside the while loop to be seen by the user only after a minute has passed ( or after `t` time).

Comment: You want to have the entire countdown printed at once once the loop has ended? Wouldn't the computer's shutdown prevent them from reading this?

Comment: i would like to have a printed message at T interval that tells the user how much time does he have until the computer shuts down. Please note that i am doing this for learning purposes :)

Comment: So, for example, every 30 seconds it prints how many minutes remain?

Comment: yeah, something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import time as t
import os

interval = 30
print("Timed Shutdown")
run = int(input("Please enter a shutdown time in minutes: "))
run *= 60
while run != 0:
    run -= 1
    t.sleep(1)
    if run % interval == 0:
        print("Your system will close in:", str(int(run/60)), "minutes")

os.system("shutdown -s")
```

If the time remaining is a multiple of `interval` the time remaining will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `display_time` variable, and then check that `run % display_time == 0`:

```py
import time as t
import os

print("Timed Shutdown")
run = int(input("Please enter a shutdown time in minutes: "))
run *= 60
display_time = 60 # number of seconds between displays
while run != 0:
    run -= 1
    t.sleep(1)
    if run % display_time == 0:
        print("Your system willl close in:", str(int(run/60)), "minutes")
print("hi")
# os.system("shutdown -s")
```